# VBA Looping through single row selections and executing concat code

Tags: vba, excel, loops

So, I've been scratching my head for a couple of hours now trying to figure this out. No matter where I look and what I do, I can't seem to make it work.

I have an excel document with ~20 columns and a completely variable number of rows. I want to concatenate each adjacent cell within the defined width (columns A:V)into the first cell (A1 for the first row), and then move to the next row and do the same until I get to the bottom. Snippet below:

[Example before and after I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ihi3.png)

I have the code that does the concatenation. To make it work I have to select the cells I want to concatenate (A1:V1), and then execute the code. Even though some cells are blank, I need the code to treat them this way and leave semicolons there. The code works exactly as I need it to, so I've been trying to wrap it in some sort of Range select, offset, loop:

```
    Dim c As Range
    Dim txt As String

    For Each c In Selection
        txt = txt & c.Value & ";"

    Next c

    Selection.ClearContents
    txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2)
    Selection(1).Value = txt
```

What I am struggling with is making the selection A1:V1, running the code, and then looping this down to A2:V1, A3:V3, etc. I think this can be done with a loops and an offset, but I cannot for the life of me work out how.

Any help at all would be much appreciated :)

Comment: make it a User Defined Function to which you supply range.

Comment: Also if you have Office 365 Excel, use the TEXTJOIN Function

Comment: I'm running this as part of a lot of other VBA code, so I don't really want to use a function as that involves manually entering the document. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding what each of you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses variant Arrays and will be very quick

```
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet4") 'change to your sheet
    'set the range to the extents of the data
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp))

    'Load data into an array
    Dim rngArr As Variant
    rngArr = rng.Value

    'create Out Bound array
    Dim OArr() As Variant
    ReDim OArr(1 To UBound(rngArr, 1), 1 To 1)

    'Loop array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
        'Combine Each Line in the array and load result into out bound array
        OArr(i, 1) = Join(Application.Index(rngArr, i, 0), ";")
    Next i

    'clear and load results
    rng.Clear
    rng.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(OArr, 1)).Value = OArr

End With
```

Comment: I am blown away by how quickly that runs, and how awesome that method is, thank you! The only other thing to ask would be; how would I make this loop through multiple worksheets within a workbook (to give some context, I have split the workbook into separate sheets based on a certain column's contents. I need to repeat this procedure on all sheets in the workbook, none of which will have consistent names when I use this in future).

Comment: There are many examples on how to loop through the sheets but you would add another For loop: `For each ws in ThisWorkbook` around the whole code above and instead of `With Worksheets("Sheet4")` you would use `With ws`  Please consider marking this as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick little script I made up to do this - the main thing to note is that I don't use selection, I used a defined range instead.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long

    Dim target As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Dim txt As String

    For i = 3 To 8
        Set target = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
        For Each c In target
            txt = txt & c.Value & ";"
        Next c
        Cells(i + 8, "A").Value2 = Left$(txt, Len(txt) - 1)
        txt = ""
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the range on the below to your requirements:

```
Sub concat_build()
    Dim buildline As String
    Dim rw As Range, c As Range
    With ActiveSheet
    For Each rw In .Range("A2:V" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Rows
        buildline = ""
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            If buildline <> "" Then buildline = buildline & ";"
            buildline = buildline & c.Value2
        Next
        rw.EntireRow.ClearContents
        rw.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1) = buildline
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, this is great! It does pretty much everything I want it to do first time around, which is amazing! The only thing I was trying to achieve was to have the range change dynamically as the number of rows will vary a lot when this is in use.

Comment: I've altered my answer to dynamically detect number of rows in column B and only do those. (I also added in the `.ClearContents` to wipe each row before writing the output.)